# Custom List troubles

Tags: java, hibernate, list, jdbc

I'm trying to put some data from DB into custom `List`. Class:

```
public class TopTitles {

    private long count;
    private String title;
    private String url;

    public long getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(long count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;

    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;

    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return count+" "+title+" "+url;
    }
}
```

And method:

```
public List<TopTitles> getTopTitlesRating() {
        Session session = null;

        session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query query = session
                .createSQLQuery("SELECT COUNT(title),title,url FROM SpyPath WHERE title!='Main page' GROUP BY title ORDER BY COUNT(title) DESC LIMIT 0, 10;");

        List<TopTitles> result = query.list();
        return result;
    }
```

Seems ok, but when I'm trying to

```
List<TopTitles> topTitlesList = spyPathService.getTopTitlesRating();
        System.out.println(topTitlesList.get(0).getTitle());
```

it shows

`java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to net.babobka.blog.domain.TopTitles`

What's wrong?

**UPD:**

This is how I changed the method:

```
public List<TopTitles> getTopTitlesRating() {
        Session session = null;

        session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query query = session
                .createSQLQuery("SELECT COUNT(title),title,url FROM SpyPath WHERE title!='Main page' GROUP BY title ORDER BY COUNT(title) DESC LIMIT 0, 10;");

        List<?> result = query.list();
        List<TopTitles> list = new ArrayList<TopTitles>();
        for(Object o : result) {
            list.add((TopTitles)o);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

And still not working/

Comment: For my own education: how does the query get executed? All the jdbc work I have done creates statements, then executes them (e.g. Stmt.execute Query()) - is this query.list a new API? Or was it in jdbc all along?

Comment: I see an answer talks about hibernate: is that where query.list comes from? should this question maybe include a hibernate tag?

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate returns a raw List from the Query.list

```
List<TopTitles> list = new ArrayList<TopTitles>();
for(Object o : result) {
    list.add((TopTitles)o);
}
```

Use this list for iteration

Comment: Sorry, do you mean this? `List<TopTitles> result = query.list();
  List<TopTitles> list = new ArrayList<TopTitles>();
  for(Object o : result) {
      list.add((TopTitles)o);
  }` Also adding another one loop doesn't seem to be efficient.

Comment: Yes. access Result list using what you have said.

Comment: Oh. Java docs says query.list() and it is obvious that it has to be cast if you want to use it. java docs says query.list() `Return the query results as a List. If the query contains multiple results pre row, the results are returned in an instance of Object[].`

Comment: I'm still having the error. Should I use your approach inside of the method or in main class?

Comment: Main Class. when result object is returned use that

Comment: and Print `sysout(list.get(0).getTitle());`

Comment: Do I have to modify method?